Django-allauth NoReverseMatch Error for 'account_login' with Custom URL Patterns
I'm working on a Django project that includes user authentication using django-allauth. I have set up custom URL patterns that include a library_slug parameter for multi-tenancy purposes. However, when I navigate to the signup page (http://localhost:8000/bgrobletest/accounts/signup/), I encounter a NoReverseMatch error:
Here is the relevant traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/williamgroble/lib_man/env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  ...
  File "/Users/williamgroble/lib_man/env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py", line 173, in get_context_data
    login_url = self.passthrough_next_url(reverse("account_login"))
  File "/Users/williamgroble/lib_man/env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 88, in reverse
    return resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/williamgroble/lib_man/env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 851, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'account_login' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<library_slug>[^/]+)/accounts/login/\\Z']

Here are my relevant files
users/urls.py:
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'users'

urlpatterns = [
    path('<slug:library_slug>/accounts/signup/', views.CustomSignupView.as_view(), name='account_signup'),
    path('<slug:library_slug>/accounts/login/', views.CustomLoginView.as_view(), name='account_login'),
    # other patterns...
]


lib_man/urls.py:
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('<slug:library_slug>/accounts/', include('users.urls', namespace='users')),
    # other patterns...
]


users/views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from allauth.account.views import SignupView
from catalog.models import Library
from .user_forms import CustomSignupForm
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class CustomSignupView(SignupView):
    form_class = CustomSignupForm
    template_name = 'account/signup.html'  # Set the custom template

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        library_slug = kwargs.get('library_slug')
        logger.debug(f"Dispatching signup view with request: {request}")
        logger.debug(f"Library slug from URL kwargs: {library_slug}")

        if not library_slug:
            logger.error("No library_slug provided in URL kwargs.")
            raise ValueError("No library_slug provided.")

        self.library = get_object_or_404(Library, slug=library_slug)
        logger.debug(f"Library object found: {self.library}")

        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['library_slug'] = self.library.slug
        return context

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['library'] = self.library
        logger.debug(f"Form kwargs: {kwargs}")
        return kwargs

It seems that the issue arises because the reverse function in allauth is trying to generate a URL for 'account_login' without providing the required library_slug argument.  I have tried messing with the urls files every which way and I cannot figure it out.
Questions:
How can I correctly pass the library_slug parameter to the reverse function in this context?
Is there a better approach to handling multi-tenancy with django-allauth?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Customizing allatuh to add in your multitenancy might be very tedious as you'd have to override quite a lot of code. Why don't you simply take that slug as part of the query string?

@AbdulAzizBarkat thanks for helping!  I am new to django so not sure what you mean by "take that slug as part of the query string"?  and are you saying i should just not use django-allauth at all?

No, where do I say that? You can find what a query string is quite easily (Its not even a Django specific thing) by searching using your preferred search engine. For instance see this Wikipedia article

@AbdulAzizBarkat I see what youre saying.  I know what a query string is, I am just wondering why that does not count as customizing allauth.  ?={slug} vs having it in the url path seems pretty similar to me.

Everything after the ? is a querystring, The url patterns don't match the ? and the querystring and any key value pair can be sent through it.
